# How to communicate between Django and Twisted when implementing a publish-subscribe pattern?

Tags: python, django, websocket, twisted, publish-subscribe

I'm implementing a WebSocket server using Python and Autobahn (something that builds off of Twisted). What's the best way to let my Autobahn/Twisted server know that something has happened from within my Django application?

More specifically, I'm implementing a notifications service and instant update service that automatically let's my client side application know when things have changed and what it needs to update.

Is there any way to allow Django to "publish" to my Twisted server and then update the client side? I'm not really sure how this should all look.

Thanks

Comment: How do these pieces relate to each other?  Are you running Django into Twisted's WSGI container (if not, why not)?  Are they separate processes?  Do they run on the same host?

Comment: They are separate processes. The only thing that relates them right now would be that they both use models.py to check the same database for updates.

Comment: You might reconsider running Django under Twisted's WSGI container. If you do so, publishing via Autobahn from Django (which then runs on a background worker thread pool) is as easy as `callFromThread` into Autobahn running on main thread, which then does the publishing.

Comment: Here is the basic bits (easy to extend to use Autobahn): https://github.com/oberstet/scratchbox/blob/master/python/twisted/wsgi/test.py

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens or hundreds of ways to do inter-process communication.  For example, you could use HTTP by running an HTTP server in one process and using an HTTP client in the other.

The specific choice of protocol probably doesn't matter a whole lot.  The particular details of the kind of communication you need might suggest one protocol over the others.  If the extent of your requirements are just to provide notification that "something has happened" then a very simple protocol will probably do the job just fine.

Comment: So how would that look in either Twisted or Django? I have several different updates that I'd like my Twisted server to send and they all depend on what client is connected. I only want to send updates if they are relevant. Here's the flow: something happens in Django -> the twisted server somehow picks that up (that's where your answer comes in) -> the client receives the update and does something.

Comment: For instance, you might run a web server in twisted (instantiate a `twisted.web.server.Site`) and then hit it with a client from Django (using `urllib`, `urllib2`, `urllib3`, `requests`, or any one of the dozens of other HTTP client libraries in Python).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the autobahn.js library? You can connect directly from the browser to your webscoket backend. Not only can you call autobahn RPC apis, but you can also do pub/sub.

http://autobahn.ws/js/

Make an autobahn server that supports RPC end-points and pubsub is the basic answer. When a client connects, the server sends RPC end-points it can access, and the client can then call them at will, also the client can subscribe to a channel and the server can then call the publish API to push messages to any subscribed client. Not sure if you've seen it, but there are many examples of various configurations github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/… –

Comment: My question mentioned autobahn. What I want is a bit more specific than that.

Comment: Make an autobahn server that supports RPC end-points and pubsub is the basic answer. When a client connects, the server sends RPC end-points it can access, and the client can then call them at will, also the client can subscribe to a channel and the server can then call the publish API to push messages to any subscribed client. Not sure if you've seen it, but there are many examples of various configurations https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp

Comment: That helps quite a bit! Please add that to your answer and then I'll accept it.